# How to exclude a dependency from parent pom to the child?

Tags: java, maven

In the parent pom I have scope of junit at test and I want to keep as it is but at a specific child, I want to use the junit at the production code because it is a test util so it is relative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can define a property `junit.scope` and set it to `test` in the parent. You use it for the scope of the dependency (again in parent).

Then you can overwrite it to `compile` in the relevant project.